# (C) String Changing Withing Data Structure When I Don't Want It To

Tags: c, string

Before I start, here is the block of code that is causing me problems.

```
typedef struct SymbPair{
    char *symbol;
    int memoryAddress;
}SymbPair;

typedef struct SymbTable{
    SymbPair *pairs;
    int numberOfItems;
} SymbTable;

SymbTable createTable(){
  SymbTable table;
  table.pairs =  (SymbPair*) calloc(1,sizeof(SymbPair));
  table.numberOfItems = 0;
  return table;
}

int checkForColon(char *word){
  if (word[strlen(word) - 1] == ':'){
    return  1;
  } else {
  return 0;
  }
}

void removeLastChar(char *word, char *buffer){
  int size = strlen(word);
  char blank[size - 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
    blank[i] = word[i];
  }
  blank[size - 1] = '\0';
  strcpy(buffer,blank);
}

void symbPairSet(char *word, int address, SymbPair *pair){
  pair -> memoryAddress = address;
  pair -> symbol = word;
}

void addToSymbTable(SymbPair sp, SymbTable *array){
  int currentTotal = array->numberOfItems;
  array -> pairs = (SymbPair*) realloc(array->pairs,currentTotal+2);
  array->pairs[currentTotal]=sp;
  array -> numberOfItems = currentTotal + 1;
}


void firstPass(SymbTable *table, char **instructions){
  int totalLabels = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (instructions[i] != NULL){
    if (checkForColon(instructions[i])){
      char buffer[strlen(instructions[i]) - 1];
      removeLastChar(instructions[i],buffer);
      SymbPair new;
      symbPairSet(buffer,(i*4) - totalLabels,&new);
      addToSymbTable(new,table);
      totalLabels++;


  }
    i++;
}

}


int main(){
SymbTable table = createTable();
firstPass(&table,instructionArray);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

First pass takes in an array of strings and looks for strings that end in a colon and then removes the colon and adds the edited string into an array of symbol pairs which is held in a struct call symb table that holds the array and its size. With my current input there should be one item in the array with symbol loop and address 8. My issue is that within the firstPass function the string has the correct value but once it is passed into the value in main it changes completely. The value for the symbol (or the string) changes from inside the firstPass function to when it is being assigned in the main but it should be the same. Any help?

[Here is a link to an image of the debugger after the SymbPair is first set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKVak.png)

[Here is what happens only a few steps afer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jygH3.jpg)

Comment: `void removeLastChar` why would you create a temporary array? You first copy the characters to temporary array then copy the temporary array to the destination... just copy the characters to the destination as they are in the loop. Adding to the answer below: `char buffer[strlen(instructions[i]) - 1];` is also too small, would remove 2 characters. And also `buffer` is a variable length aray, it stops existing after `}` in `while` loop  - all `pair -> symbol = word;` are invalid and point to the same `buffer`...

Comment: would I need to copy in the string to SymbPair->word then?

Answer (score 2):

If you have this:

```
char blank[size - 1];
```

then this

```
blank[size - 1] = '\0';
```

is writing outside your array as it only has elements 0 to size - 2

if you write outside your variables you're changing other data, which seems consistent with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Another thing that 's wring is in the line `array -> pairs = (SymbPair*) realloc(array->pairs,currentTotal+2);`  there should be a `*sizeof(SymbPair)` somewhere in the size calculation (as size is in bytes)...